# Error in a very basic program using javascript

Tags: javascript

If `person` is not `null`, then output the first condition, else show an alert box. But it doesn't execute the second condition if `null` is entered - it continues with first condition.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var person = prompt("Please enter your name");

    if (person != null) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
    }
    else if (person == null ){
            alert("How dare you ?>");
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wrap your `script tag` inside `head tag`. Since `myFunction()` will not be defined when assigning event handler for the button. Or use `addEventListener` to bind your events.

Comment: is that really necessary here ? I'm using w3 schools tryit live
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt
Just change it to my script and run

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy that's incorrect.

Comment: @torazaburo Is it? It seems I had a misunderstanding.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy `myFunction()` does **not** need to be defined at the time of assignment to the `onclick` handler. It needs to be defined when the handler is *called*, which would be when the click happens. In any case, the problem you are worried about does not match the behavior reported by the OP. If in fact the problem were what you mentioned, an undefined function error would result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you're not actually entering null when you think you are.

`null` is special: it's a special value that represents the absence of a value. Not to be confused with `"null"`, the string containing the word "null", or "", the empty string.

`prompt()` returns `null` only when cancelled. When you "enter null", you're probably ending up with either "null" or "", depending on if you type anything in the box.

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

So your fixed code would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var person = prompt("Please enter your name");

    if (person != "") {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
    } else {
        alert("How dare you ?>");
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right, but as I explained, "entering nothing" is really getting you the empty string, not null.

Comment: To get the behaviour you apparently want, change the `!= null` to `!= ""`

Comment: Note, also, that you don't need to put the opposite condition in an "else if" block, you can just (if you only have the one branch), have else by itself (which will of course imply the opposite of the condition given in the `if`)

Comment: But `prompt` does return null when cancelled.

Answer (score -1):

myFunction() is not defining when button is assigning event handler so put script in head tag. And for check the string value need to put "" instead of null

I modified your code try this it will work...it is working fine for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
         <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var person = prompt("Please enter your name");

        if (person != "") {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
            "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
    }
        else {
                alert("How dare you ?>");
    }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I modified answer, try that it is working you were comparing with null but null also string value so you need to compare like person=="" and person!=""

Comment: `myfunction` does not need to be defined when assigning it to `onClick`. It just needs to be defined when the click actually occurs, which it is.

Comment: How will this behave if the user cancels the alert? Also, why are you using `innerHTML` when you are merely assigning the textual content of an element? Also, please indent your code properly.